# /answers API request returns no tags if body_markdown is included

Tags: bug, api, tags, answers, api-v2.2

This API request to `/answers` has the filter set to return the `tags` field for the corresponding question. It works fine:

[api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers#filter=!9YdnSPElz](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers#order=desc&sort=creation&filter=!9YdnSPElz&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

But, when the filter is modified to include the `answer.body_markdown` field too, the `tags` field is always an empty array:

[api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers#filter=!-%2Af%286t0WWOP6](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/answers#order=desc&sort=creation&filter=!-%2Af%286t0WWOP6&site=stackoverflow&run=true)

Comment: Confirmed‌​‌​‌​.

Comment: Is there any solutions to this yet? It's still happening to me here.